# How can I display the first and last record of the same category wordpress?

Tags: php, wordpress, custom-post-type

I have a function that should rather display a link to the first or last record which is in the same category as the pulling one, but by clicking on the "forward" or "back" button, it then switches between two records, although there are three in the category , or, in the category where one record, throws on the records of another category. And I need him, after there are no entries left, from the last one he can switch to the first record from the SAME CATEGORY and from the FIRST record to the LAST as there is a back button with the SAME CATEGORY

```
 function da_the_adjacent_post_link( $course = '' ){
  global $post;
  $course = ( $course == 'prev' ) ? true : false;
  $order  = ( $course ) ? 'DESC' : 'ASC';
  $class  = ( $course ) ? 'prev' : 'next';

  $link = get_adjacent_post_link( '%link', '%title', true, '', $course );

  if ( ! $link ){
    $term = get_the_terms( $post->ID, 'category' );
    $term = $term[0];
    $article = get_posts([
      'post_type' => portfolio,
      'post_per_page' => 1,
      'exclude'     => $post->ID,
      'category'    => $term->term_id,
      'order'       => $order
    ]);

    if ( empty($article) )
      return false;
    else
      $article = $article[0];

    $link = sprintf( '<a href="' . get_the_permalink($article->ID) . '"> ');
  }

  echo $link;

}




if( get_adjacent_post(true,'',true) ) {
  previous_post_link('%link', '<div class="icon-button">');
} else {
  da_the_adjacent_post_link( $course = '' ); ?>
};

if( get_adjacent_post(true, '', false)){
   next_post_link('%link', ' <div class="icon-button">')
} else {
   da_the_adjacent_post_link( $course = '' ); ?>
};
```

Comment: Shouldn't the `if( get_adjacent_post() )` become: `if( get_adjacent_post(true) )`? because the default parameter for `$in_same_term` is false, and you want the result be in the same category of current post.

Comment: For some reason, he doesn’t show one record out of three, but shows only two

Comment: He only works ```else``` part